# Frequency range of acoustic feedback

Tags: spectrogram, feedback

What is the frequency range in which acoustic feedback can be found?  Most importantly, is there some lowest frequency below which one can expect not to find any feedback?

My conclusion from the reading I've done and from working with a limited number of audio feedback samples is that it can be found anywhere from 900 Hz upward. However, I've also found an [example](http://www.freesound.org/people/zerolagtime/sounds/269446/) where 
the feedback in question shows up in the spectrogram around 550 Hz.  Now, the creator of that sound may well have shifted the sound's pitch down after recording it (I've asked the uploader and I'll wait for an answer).  But in any case, it made me wonder if such a situation actually might arise in practice.

Comment: What kind of system are you talking about? PA/Monitor to Microphone feedback? Something else? In any case, the frequency range is limited by the components involved and their frequency response.

Comment: Yes, I would be interested in an answer for PA/Monitor to microphone feedback, but I'm also curious about for instance the situation where a user experiences feedback from a headset-microphone device, or any other situation where acoustic feedback is produced.  It's true that I would be interested as to specifics detailing how, numerically speaking, the relevant components and their frequency responses influence the frequencies of the feedback.  But what I'd most like to know is simply which frequencies I might find the feedback upon looking at a spectrogram.

Comment: A spectrogram of what?

Comment: A spectrogram of the recording from the microphone (where the recording contains feedback).

Comment: The distance between the mic and speaker affects the feedback frequency.  A large enough distance (tens of meters) might allow low frequency feedback if within the passband of the system with enough bass gain.

Comment: Interesting. In practice, how often and where does it occur that you have such low frequency feedback? I could imagine such a thing happening in the case of an auditorium setting where the bass is turned way up.  But based on what you're saying, it seems unlikely that there'd be such a problem in the case of a home theater system, a wedding banquet (where the overall gain would presumably not be as loud as in an auditorium) or some setting smaller than an auditorium.   Is what I'm saying accurate or am I missing something?

Comment: @itsumozenzen,  Think about the pickup on a bass guitar.

Comment: Also consider pickup from hearing aid loops and well as from speakers.   Anything with a coil may result in feedback from a hearing aid loop.